# mysql order by values and then show the rest

Tags: mysql

I want to order the results of a mysql query

1) to show first entrys wich match a given condition and order them randomly

2) and then show the rest of the results ordered by date desc

i tryed already this:

```
Select * from post inner join user on post.user_id = user.id order by user.type = "top" desc, created desc;
```

many thanks

Comment: You need to write 2 selects and use union between them

Comment: actually my goal was to do it without union, as this query is part of a complex filter action, maybe you have an alternative, but many thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` statement

```
select * from post 
inner join user on post.user_id = user.id 
order by case when user.type = 'top' 
              then 1 
              else 2 
         end asc, 
         created desc;
```

Comment: great, works perfectly